# Two column CSS-layout for HTML-form

Tags: html, css, layout

I need a HTML-form with a two-column-layout (label - input). The problem is that the left column holding the labels depends on some user input, so I can't use a fixed width (e.g. 150px). The result should look like this:

```
   First name:   [ <INPUT> ]
   Last name:    [ <INPUT> ]
   Gender:       [ <INPUT> ]
```

Tried a lot of possible solutions with float-layout but couldn't find a working one.

Comment: If it looks like a table...and this does, use a `table`. It's allowed.

Comment: I remember to have heard that using a table just for layout is deprecated? One should use CSS instead (correct me, if I'm wrong).

Comment: Nope, tables are fine in certain circumstances, tabular data (which this clearly is) and forms are the usual options. Tables for page layout,,,absolutely not...but if it looks like data that should be in a table...it's OK to use one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could either use a HTML `<table>` or the CSS `display:table` like the following demo.

http://jsfiddle.net/vn9dt5Lv/

```css
.form {
    display: table;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.form > li {
    display: table-row;
}
.form > li > div {
    display: table-cell;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.form > li > div:first-child {
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="form">
    <li>
        <div><label>First name:</label></div>
        <div><input type="text" /></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div><label>Last name:</label></div>
        <div><input type="text" /></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div><label>Gender:</label></div>
        <div><input type="radio" name="g" />Male <input type="radio" name="g" />Female</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, seems to be a real good solution :-) Just another question: what can I do if I want the second column (holding the inputs) to use the full remaining width of the page (which is depending on the width of the first column). Tried this by setting width of all elements in your example but couldn't figure out a working solution. Seems like the table-cells always use 50% of the screen?!?!?

Comment: Perfect, I've just added `.form > li > div > input[type=text] {
    width: 100%;
}` to the CSS, now it works like expected :-)

Comment: @Peter yes, and you could also add box-sizing rules - `.form > li > div > input[type=text] { width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; }` make sure it's all fit inside the cell, similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30040893/483779) I answered recently