# Select and textarea not correctly aligned

Tags: html, css

i'm having an annoying problem with CSS/HTML.

As the image follows:
[image: Alignment problem]

I want the textarea and select to be aligned correctly, but it's not working.

These are the CSS of the elements:

Main div (where the elements are):

```
#janela
{
    position: absolute;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    top: 30%;
    left: 40%;
    margin-top: -140px;
    margin-left: -170px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}
```

Select CSS:

```
#usuario
{
    border-color: black;
    width:100%;
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Textarea css:

```
    .post-body
{
    width: 580pt;
    height: auto;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI',sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: black;
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    resize:vertical;
}
```

Button css:

```
    .newPostContent.btn
{
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 45px;
}
```

I use 100% width for compatibility stuff, so how do I make those elements aligned correctly?

Comment: I'm sure `box-sizing: border-box` will be extremely useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the form elements have default borders and padding. You can set [`box-sizing:border-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) to make them to be included of the total box size.

```css
select,
input,
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <select>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
</p>
<p>
  <textarea></textarea>
</p>
<p>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</p>
```